# How to pass parameters and get returned exit value to/from a batch file in c++ windows

Tags: c++, batch-file

**CONTEXT :**

-Windows 10

-C++

-Batch file

-I want to call a `.bat` file in a `.cpp` file and get an `int` as return value

-The batch file counts and renames `.jpg` files in a given folder passed as parameter

-Batch file code:

```
::%1 is the path to the base folder
::%2 is the name of the folder of the images
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

CD /D %1
set cnt=0
for %%f in (%2\*) do (
    set newName=000!cnt!
    set newName=!newname:~-4!
    ren %%f !newName!.jpg
    set /a cnt+=1
)

@echo %cnt% files renamed in order
exit /b %cnt%
```

**QUESTION :**

I think I already know how to pass parameters... You need put spaces after the .bat file you call and enter the wanted parameters.

ex:

To run my script in the `L:/baseFolder/water` folder, I would use :

`system(file.bat L:\\baseFolder water)`

How do I get the `cnt` value returned with `exit /b %cnt%` as a variable in my cpp file?

Am I supposed to use `exit` to get this integer?

**Bonus:** What if I want to return multiple values?

Comment: _How do I get the cnt value returned with exit /b %cnt% as a variable in my cpp file?_ is answered on MSDN: [`system()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx): _If command is not NULL, system returns the value that is returned by the command interpreter._ I believe this is the value returned by `exit` of your batch script (according to this link [`EXIT`](https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html)).

Comment: Concerning the bonus: You could write the output of batch into a file which is read afterwards. Piping batch standard output into the standard input of caller might be another option.

Comment: `int i = system(".....")` returns 0 every time ): Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the idea!

Comment: _returns 0 every time_ I don't understand - the output in my answer isn't fake. Did you check whether the batch file could be found? May be, it is even not started. When I tested in VS I set working directory to the folder with bat file (in debug settings) to be sure that it is found.

Comment: nevermind! I forgot to double my backslashes in the paths passed in params %1 and %2! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN describes the usage of [`system()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx). I cite the part about return value:

> If `command` is `NULL` and the command interpreter is found, returns a nonzero value. If the command interpreter is not found, returns `0` and sets `errno` to `ENOENT`. If `command` is not `NULL`, system returns the value that is returned by the command interpreter. It returns the value `0` only if the command interpreter returns the value `0`.

Somehow, I assumed that return code of batch file is the return code of command interpreter but I was not fully sure nor I found an appropriate doc. concerning this.

Thus, I made a little sample and tried it locally.

`testExitBat.cc`:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int ret = system("testExitBat.bat Hello");
  std::cout << "testExitBat.bat returned " << ret << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

`testExitBat.bat`:

```bat
::%1 an argument
echo "$1: '"%1%"'"
exit /b 123
```

I compiled and ran it on VS2013 (Windows 10):

```
C:\Users\Scheff>echo "$1: '"Hello"'"
"$1: '"Hello"'"

C:\Users\Scheff>exit /b 123
testExitBat.bat returned 123
```

Answer (score 0):

Both g++ and vs have the filesystem header under experimental, which may be a better solution.  If you prefer the environmental variable solution then std::getenv will do that.

It's been a long time since I've done any batch file programming, but I seem to remember that you can set environmental variables in there.